# Why is the command executed outside the condition brackets?

Tags: autohotkey

Please help me understand why, after executing a command in a condition, the command executes outside the condition?

**Here is the script**

```
^+Enter::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
if WinActive("Visual Studio Code")
  Send 1
else
  Send 0

BS:: Send WTF
```

**Condition:**

```
When you press the combination "Ctrl + Shift + Enter" ::
If the window contains the title "Visual Studio Code"
- insert 1
Otherwise
- insert 0
```

**Instructions outside the conditions:**

```
When you click the "Backspace" button, insert "WTF"
```

**Current result:**

```
If the condition is true, instead of "1" is inserted "1WTF"
If the condition is not true, instead of "0" is inserted "0WFT"
```

Comment: It will keep executing until it reaches a `Return` or the end of your script. See if sticking a `Return` after your `Send 0` line fixes the issue.

Comment: @EJE, Thank you so much

Comment: @EJE, Maybe you can tell me at the same time, when sending the keyboard shortcut `Send {ctrl down} {shift down} {Enter} {ctrl up} {shift up}`, can i avoid switching the keyboard language if it is set to `Ctrl + Shift`. I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like this (not tested):

```
#ifwinactive, Visual Studio Code : The following code is ONLY active when VS is active
   ^+Enter::
      Send, 1
   Return
#ifwinactive ; End VS

^+Enter:: ; Ctrl-Enter behaviour outside of VS
Send, 0
Return
```